# How can i detect screen is recording in React Native

Tags: javascript, java, android, typescript, react-native

I'm doing an app that play music, I would like my music is private so i don't want user can use screen record to record the screen or my music in React Native i have do this in MainActivity.java

`getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);`

it make my screen go dark but user still record my music